# Problem with Database ”Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string”

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

Error: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string. I tried everything, I think and I cannot solve it.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'C:/dev/FlaskBlog/blog.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Blogpost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(20))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Problem appears when I try to post an article.

Here is addpost route:

```
@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        subtitle = request.form['subtitle']
        author = request.form['author']
        content = request.form['content']

        post = Blogpost(title=title, subtitle=subtitle, author=author, date_posted=datetime.now())

        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: You need to fix path on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

**There are no test files here, so I can not test**.
But I have encountered the **same error**, and my database is `SQLite`. The following codes work fine for me:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# relative path on Linux: with three slashes
e = create_engine('sqlite:///relative/path/to/database.db')

# absolute path on Linux: with four slashes
e = create_engine('sqlite:////absolute/path/to/database.db')

# absolute path on Windows
e = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\database.db')
```

And in your case, I think you can change `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'C:/dev/FlaskBlog/blog.db'` to `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\dev\\FlaskBlog\\blog.db'`.

For detailed documents: [SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html)

Answer (score -1):

The **SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI** should be a valid db uri, fix that and it should work. I also struggled with the same problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give some hints on what a "valid db uri" looks like or where OP might find this info.